# When I want to build a big matrix, my code becomes extremely slow. Why?

Tags: r

I have big data frame and I want to build a special matrix out of  it. but when I'm trying to create this matrix, my code become extremely slow after around 500 iterations in for loop. I put the print(i) to keep track of progress of my script. it's start very fast, but it become slow and slower. if it's run like this, I think I should waite few months!

Would anyone help me to speed up this code or make it parallel?

Here is my code and steps:

A) Information about the size and length of variables:

```
dim(tars.hsa)
[1] 737857      2 
> length(ind.mirs)
[1] 737857
> length(lclus)
[1] 737857
```

To have an idea about the entries of ***lclus***:

```
    [8977]  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
    [99001]  2  2  1  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
    [99025]  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
    [99049]  2  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
    [99073]  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
    [99097]  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  5  5  5
    [99121]  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  3  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  2  2  2


> tars.hsa[1:10,]
                miR.Family Gene.Symbol
2     miR-23abc/miR-23b-3p        A1BG
19        miR-218/miR-218a        A1BG
121 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
130 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
143 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
147 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
153 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
157 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
201                miR-433        A1CF
215                miR-433        A1CF
>
```

Here is my code,

Step one:

```
# separate out individual miRs of one cluster
ind.mirs <- strsplit(tars.hsa[, "miR.Family"], split="/")
lclus    <- unlist(lapply(ind.mirs, length))
```

Step Two(The slowest step after few hundereds iterations):

```
new.tars <- NULL
for( i in 1:length(ind.mirs)){
  add.tar <- matrix(data=rep(tars.hsa[i,], times=lclus[i]), ncol=2, byrow=T)
  add.tar[,1] <-  ind.mirs[[i]]  # substitute miR cluster w/ individual miR
  new.tars <- rbind(new.tars, add.tar)
 print(i)
}
```

Comment: Because you are in the [second circle of hell](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: everytime you use `rbind` the whole data gets copied, modified and then replaced in memory. This is very time (& memory) consuming...

Comment: @ChristianBorck, what can I use insted of rbind ?

Comment: read the link @joran provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that someone can improve on the following, but it is best to avoid loops where possible and use built in functions. I suggest something like:

```
#Make up some simple data to run it on
tars.hsa <- data.frame(miR.Family=c("a","b/b","c/c","d/d/d"), Gene.Symbol=paste0("A",1:4,"BG"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ind.mirs <- strsplit(tars.hsa[, "miR.Family"], split="/")

lclus    <- sapply(ind.mirs, length)
new.tars <- matrix(NA,sum(lclus),2)
new.tars[,1] <- do.call(c,ind.mirs)
new.tars[,2] <- rep(tars.hsa$Gene.Symbol, each=lclus )
```

Obviously I can't test how much quicker it is on your data, so can you tell us how it works.

Comment: seems nice solution, but I got this error :    > new.tars[,2] <- rep(tars.hsa$Gene.Symbol, each=lclus )
Error in new.tars[, 2] <- rep(tars.hsa$Gene.Symbol, each = lclus) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
In addition: Warning message:
In rep.default(tars.hsa$Gene.Symbol, each = lclus) :
  first element used of 'each' argument

Comment: try using `times=lclus` instead of `each=...` within the `rep` function

Comment: it's supper fast, Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the second circle, you can use vectorized functions. Here is an example.

```
# Read data.
tars.hsa<-read.table(textConnection('miR.Family Gene.Symbol
2     miR-23abc/miR-23b-3p        A1BG
19        miR-218/miR-218a        A1BG
121 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
130 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
143 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
147 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
153 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
157 miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p        A1CF
201                miR-433        A1CF
215                miR-433        A1CF'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


ind.mirs <- strsplit(tars.hsa[, "miR.Family"], split="/")
# lclus    <- unlist(lapply(ind.mirs, length))
lclus    <- sapply(ind.mirs, length)

# A single vectorized statement.
new.tars<-cbind(unlist(ind.mirs),
                rep(tars.hsa$Gene.Symbol,times=lclus))


# [,1]          [,2]  
# [1,] "miR-23abc"   "A1BG"
# [2,] "miR-23b-3p"  "A1BG"
# [3,] "miR-218"     "A1BG"
# [4,] "miR-218a"    "A1BG"
# [5,] "miR-376abd"  "A1CF"
# [6,] "miR-376b-3p" "A1CF"
# [7,] "miR-376abd"  "A1CF"
# [8,] "miR-376b-3p" "A1CF"
# [9,] "miR-376abd"  "A1CF"
# [10,] "miR-376b-3p" "A1CF"
# [11,] "miR-376abd"  "A1CF"
# [12,] "miR-376b-3p" "A1CF"
# [13,] "miR-376abd"  "A1CF"
# [14,] "miR-376b-3p" "A1CF"
# [15,] "miR-376abd"  "A1CF"
# [16,] "miR-376b-3p" "A1CF"
# [17,] "miR-433"     "A1CF"
# [18,] "miR-433"     "A1CF"
```

Comment: Nice solution, just seconds before I was about to post the same. Good work! :) (The speedup for the OP would be interesting though..)

Comment: it's run very fast, but for the second column instead of Gene.Symbol, i have number, but I don't know why!     ` [,1]         [,2]
[1,] "miR-23abc"  "1" 
[2,] "miR-23b-3p" "1" 
[3,] "miR-218"    "1" 
[4,] "miR-218a"   "1" `

Comment: what does `str(tars.hsa)` tell you? All character columns?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `rbind` as it reallocates the whole `new.tars` and copies it to the new location at each step of the loop. To speed things up preallocate the matrix in advance and fill it in in the loop. Something like:

```
new.tars = matrix(0, length(ind.mirs), length(ind.mirs));
for( i in 1:length(ind.mirs)){
  ...
  new.tars[,i] <- add.tar;
  print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
tars.hsa <- data.frame(
    miR.Family=c('miR-23abc/miR-23b-3p', 'miR-218/miR-218a', 'miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p', 'miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p', 'miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p', 'miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p', 'miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p', 'miR-376abd/miR-376b-3p', 'miR-433', 'miR-433'),
    Gene.Symbol=c('A1BG','A1BG','A1CF','A1CF','A1CF','A1CF','A1CF','A1CF','A1CF','A1CF')
)

do.call(rbind, apply(tars.hsa, 1, function(row) {
    data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names=NULL,
        miR.Family=strsplit(row['miR.Family'], '/'),
        Gene.Symbol=row['Gene.Symbol']
    )
}))
```